# superfine stage control in ARM200

Tags: dm-script

I was wondering if there was any way to control the "superfine" stage controls on an ARM200F through digital micrograph script commands.
The usual EMsetstageXY(xposition, yposition) will only allow for positioning of the stage by the motor controls to about 25nm precision and does not affect the superfine stage values.

I would like to be able to write a script that can control the stage position with superfine controls.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, such a command does not exist. The piezo-controls of the ARM200F are not exposed to the scripting language.